# python ValueError: value is not in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I am trying to write a program that gets data from a db and print them sorted. When I'm sorting my final list, I have this error:

```
    employee_list.pop (employee_list.index (max_weight_path))
ValueError: ('mahdi', 90, 190) is not in list
```

but this is my sample list:

```
[('amin', 75, 180), ('mahdi', 90, 190), ('mamad', 75, 175), ('ahmad', 60, 175)]
```

and finally my code snippet:

```
sorted_employee = []
max_weight = 0 
max_weight_path = ''
i = len (employee_list)

for z in range (i):
    for x in employee_list:
        if x[2] > max_weight:
            max_weight = x[2]
            max_weight_path = x
        elif x[2] == max_weight:
            if x[1] < max_weight_path[1]:
                max_weight_path = x
    sorted_employee.append (max_weight_path)
    employee_list.pop (employee_list.index (max_weight_path))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sorting a list using `.sort`

You don't need to code your own sorting algorithm, there is a pretty efficient one builtin: [Python Documentation Sorting: HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

```py
from operator import itemgetter
employee_list = [('amin', 75, 180), ('mahdi', 90, 190), ('mamad', 75, 175), ('ahmad', 60, 175)]
employee_list.sort(key=itemgetter(2))
print(employee_list)
# [('mamad', 75, 175), ('ahmad', 60, 175), ('amin', 75, 180), ('mahdi', 90, 190)]
```

Or equivalently:

```py
employee_list = [('amin', 75, 180), ('mahdi', 90, 190), ('mamad', 75, 175), ('ahmad', 60, 175)]
employee_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
print(employee_list)
# [('mamad', 75, 175), ('ahmad', 60, 175), ('amin', 75, 180), ('mahdi', 90, 190)]
```

### Fixing your code

You use two nested `for`-loop and never reinitialize `max_weight` during two runs of the inner loop. After the first run of the inner loop, `max_weight` contains the maximum value from the initial list; thus the subsequence runs cannot update it, because remaining elements of the list all have smaller value. Hence your inner loop keep trying to `pop` the max element from the initial list, instead of popping the max, then the second-largest, then the third-largest, etc.

Just move the initialization of `max_weight` inside the outer loop, just before the beginning of the inner loop:

```py
sorted_employee = []
i = len (employee_list)

for z in range (i):
    max_weight = 0
    max_weight_path = ''
    for x in employee_list:
        if x[2] > max_weight:
            max_weight = x[2]
            max_weight_path = x
        elif x[2] == max_weight:
            if x[1] < max_weight_path[1]:
                max_weight_path = x
    sorted_employee.append (max_weight_path)
    employee_list.pop (employee_list.index (max_weight_path))

print(sorted_employee)
# [('mahdi', 90, 190), ('amin', 75, 180), ('ahmad', 60, 175), ('mamad', 75, 175)]
```

### General debugging principles

The interpreter tells you `ValueError: ('mahdi', 90, 190) is not in list` yet you are sure that `('mahdi', 90, 190)` should be in the list. What happened?

The first thing you can do is add a `print` statement just before the `pop` statement which raised the exception, to print out the values of of all variables and understand what is going on:

```py
sorted_employee = []
max_weight = 0 
max_weight_path = ''
i = len (employee_list)

for z in range (i):
    for x in employee_list:
        if x[2] > max_weight:
            max_weight = x[2]
            max_weight_path = x
        elif x[2] == max_weight:
            if x[1] < max_weight_path[1]:
                max_weight_path = x
    sorted_employee.append (max_weight_path)
    print('DEBUG z={}:\n  max_weight_path={}\n  employee_list  ={}\n  sorted_employee={}'.format(z, max_weight_path, employee_list, sorted_employee))
    employee_list.pop (employee_list.index (max_weight_path))
```

Output:

```
DEBUG z=0:
  max_weight_path=('mahdi', 90, 190)
  employee_list  =[('amin', 75, 180), ('mahdi', 90, 190), ('mamad', 75, 175), ('ahmad', 60, 175)]
  sorted_employee=[('mahdi', 90, 190)]
('mahdi', 90, 190)
DEBUG z=1:
  max_weight_path=('mahdi', 90, 190)
  employee_list  =[('amin', 75, 180), ('mamad', 75, 175), ('ahmad', 60, 175)]
  sorted_employee=[('mahdi', 90, 190), ('mahdi', 90, 190)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in <module>
ValueError: ('mahdi', 90, 190) is not in list
```

This way you probably would have found out what the problem was: we keep trying to remove `'mahdi'` from `employee_list` and adding it to `sorted_employee`, which fails the second time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you are trying to do in your code, but this is how I'd do it.
First make a copy if you want to keep the original order in a seperate list.
After use the sort method and use the lambda function for the key. The key is the value used to sort by. The x in the lambda function points to the tuple inside the list.
So it uses the third element of the tuple (index 2) to sort by.

If you don't want a copy you can simply sort the original list. If you want to sort by the second element (which i believe is the weight) than you should use x[1].

```
employee_list = [('amin', 75, 180), ('mahdi', 90, 190), ('mamad', 75, 175), ('ahmad', 
60, 175)]
sorted_employee = employee_list[:]
sorted_employee.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])

print(sorted_employee)
```

Comment: If you're going to copy the list, you can write directly `sorted_employee = sorted(employee_list, key=lambda x: x[2])`.